# Node error: illegal or missing argument for command line flat. switch

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

I am reeving error when using spawn in Node.js 4.4.4

> Node error: illegal or missing argument for command line flat. switch

Here my code:

```
    var bat = require.resolve('../src/util/bs/build.bat');
    var profile = require.resolve('../profiles/profile.js');
    var profileStr = '--profile' + ' ' + profile;
    var ls = spawn(bat, [profileStr]);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
```

The .bat file run properly when called from command prompt like:

```
"C:\Projects\xxx\src\util\bs\build.bat --profile C:\Projects\xxx\profiles\app.profile.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue passing arguments to .bat using an array.

Example:

```
var bat = require.resolve('../src/util/bs/build.bat');
var profile = require.resolve('../profiles/profile.js');

var ls = spawn(bat, ['--profile', profile]);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```